# Python Design Pattern for data transformations

Tags: python, mongodb, design-patterns

I find myself doing something like this quite a bit:

```
if 'id' in kwargs:
    query['_id'] = ObjectID(kwargs.pop('id'))
if 'name' in kwargs:
    query['event'] = kwargs.pop('name')
if 'keywords' in kwargs:
    keywords = kwargs.pop('keywords')
    query['keywords'] = {
        '$in': keywords
    }
```

Ignore the implementation specifics. The essential point here is that I'm dealing with two data structures which share similar data and performing both simple, repetitive and more complex transformations.

**Are there any design patterns or other developer-friendly ways of making these types of transformations easier to code?**

I thought about creating a table and associated function to transform simple attribute names but I have a feeling that won't play well when dealing with more complicated data transformations. Also, that method may not save me a whole lot of work in the long run.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You're working with MongoDB queries?

Comment: Yeah. If there's a way to make this easier with Mongo, I'm interested in hearing about it. However, I'm really looking for a 'generic' answer as I've ran into this sort of problem before completely unrelated to MongoDB (or any DB for that matter)

Comment: Maybe it's my own nitpick but I dislike checking if a key exist before accessing it. I'd simply use `try: ... except KeyError: pass`. If you use it really often you can create a context manager and use something like `with SuppressKeyError(): ...`.

Comment: Yeah, I actually agree with you there. Typically I do just go with try/except statements. This was just a quick, prototype stage of working on a class method. +1

Answer (score 2):

You could at least clean out the `if`s with a map.  I like to do that when I have a large group of transforms.

```
transforms = {'id' : ('_id', lambda val: ObjectID(val)),
              'name' : ('event', lambda val: val),
              'keywords' : ('keywords', lambda val: val)}
for kwargs_key in kwargs.keys():
    try:
        query_key, transform = transforms[kwargs_key]
    except KeyError:
        # Default or error handling
    else:
        query[query_key] = transform(kwargs.pop(kwargs_key))
```

If you wrap this in a class and make `transforms` a class or instance attribute, you can even easily add or overwrite transforms at runtime if you want.

Answer (score 2):

You might consider encapsulating the transformations in a class:

```
class QueryAdapter(object):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.kwargs = kwargs
    def __getitem__(self, item):
        try:
            method = getattr(self, item)
        except AttributeError:
            raise IndexError(item)
        else:
            return method()
    def _id(self):
        return 'ObjectID({})'.format(self.kwargs['id'])
    def event(self):
        return self.kwargs['name']
    def keywords(self):
        return {'$in': self.kwargs['keywords']}
```

Once you've defined the `QueryAdapter`, the rest of your code becomes very simple:

```
kwargs = dict(id='abc', name='def')
query = QueryAdapter(**kwargs)

print(query['_id'])
# ObjectID(abc)
print(query['event'])
# def
print(query['keywords'])
# {'$in': 'key'}
```

Comment: I really like this. It looks like a good way to use this functionality across multiple places (Django Views, API Code, and my custom Mongo Models).  I'm going to give it a try and see how flexible and re-usable it ends up being. I'll be sure to 'accept' an answer after I give everybody's suggestions a shot. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I would recommend right now would be to at least have this conversion only in a single place. So maybe define a “kwargs to query” function (eventually also the reverse?) that contains all those conversions in a single place. And then use the function wherever you need to do such conversions.

You might be able to create some more generic way that just converts a single value, but you would need to call it then multiple times as well. Not to mention that you would have to add many special cases in that generic conversion method. So instead, just keep the conversion for the full structure.